# Why can a template use $this keyword directly?

Tags: php, magento

I am a newbie at PHP; today I see some code as the following in Magento `top.phtml`.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <!--NEW HOME LINK -->
        <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></a>"</li>
        <!--NEW HOME LINK -->
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I know `$this` is the self of the `class`, it's only used in the class to refer to the method or property, on the above code, there is no  class has been defined, why it can use $this keyword directly? What does `$this->__('Home')` stand for?

Comment: __('Home') is likely a localization method for the text 'Home' used to easily convert pages to various languages.

Comment: See http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php , function __() for your entry point into Magento's translate system. For additional resources, see Alan Storm's knowledgebase articles at magento.com and when you are ready you might enjoy the free Fundamentals video available from Magento U (full disclosure: I'm the one in the videos). Good luck, and keep asking questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tagged this [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) you likely have a class like [`Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html). At least, the methods hint at that. Now, I have no clue about Magento, but this class extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and in that class you have the `fetchView` Method, [which at some point does](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php)

```
include $includeFilePath;
```

When you [`include`](http://php.net/include) code inside a method, you do have access to `$this` in the included file code, because it is evaluated in the scope of that instance:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

General Example:

```
class Template
…
    public function render($templateFile)
    {
        include $templateFile;
    }
    public function ___($stringToTranslate)
    {
        // translates $stringToTranslate somehow
    }
 }
```

Note that "`$this` is not the `self` of the class" is only partially correct. `self` is also a keyword and php, but while `self` really refers to the class, `$this` refers to the instance of a class.

Comment: Templates are included from blocks that extend `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. There is no helper in it's inheritance chain.

Comment: @clockworkgeek thanks. but tbh, I dont care about the Magento part. The example template I give above is not meant in relation to Magento at all. Updated answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The object has been defined!  This template used as instance of a block.  It's that instance that is referred to in the template.  A quick way to identify the class that you're currently dealing with inside a template is to use the following line of code in the template:

```
<?php echo get_class($this); ?>
```

Also, you mention the `__` method.  This hooks into Magento's locale system.  This means that you could write:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Hello') ?>
```

In your template, then use the same template file in your French store and only have to provide the text mapping from the English to French language instead of creating a whole new template.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is template for some block class. Block template (a `.phtml` file) is included inside `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class `fetchView()` method. You can go to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php` and see how it is done. That's why `$this` is available in `.phtml`. You can read more about magento block and templates in [this Alan Storm's article](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates). It is slightly outdated but basic are explained very well (imho).