# How to use $this in outside of class?

Tags: php, class, object

Can we use `$this` outside of class. Please look at the example below,

```
<?php 

class Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am an Animal!";
    }

    public function sayClassName() {
        $this->whichClass();
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am a Tiger!";
    }

    public function anotherClass() {
        echo "I am a another Tiger!";
    }

}

$tigerObj = new Tiger();

//Tiger::whichClass();

$this->anotherClass();
```

Here I have created new object `$tigerObj = new Tiger();` after that I tried to use `$this` but it throwing error. So is that possible to use `$this` from outside of the class ? If no,
`$this` refers to the current object. So why don't we use this ?

Comment: Use `$tigerObj->anotherClass()` instead

Comment: you can not use `$this` outside of a class.

Comment: I knew that. But my question is can use $this instead of calling that obeject ?

Comment: You can make static method, and use like this Tiger::anotherClass. Link to (doc)[http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.static.php]

Comment: If it throws an error after you try to use `$this`, then it definitely means you **cannot use $this outside a class**, and no matter how many questions you ask or examples you provide - you can't do it. PERIOD. There are reasons for it, and it also makes ZERO sense to do that.

Comment: "`$this` refers to the current object"—yes, but not in the sense that you seem to be thinking about it. It's not "the object that I last used", it's "the object on which this method was called". So if you're not inside the scope of a member function, you don't have a `$this`. In your example, you're in global scope, so there's no object available. (Effectively, $this is a kind of magic variable that gives a pointer to the member variables of an individual object—it makes no sense to refer to it outside the scope of an object.)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? What you are asking for doesn't make any sense at all. `$this` always points to the current `instance` of the class it is used. So to refer to the `instance` of your class from outside,you have your `tigerObj` to do so.

Comment: Hi all, I have seen using $this not in a class (in template files - usually in magento). So I only I think this way. I am sorry If I bothered you. I just want to know about this. That's it.

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example of `$this` being used outside a class? We may be able to help you understand what's going on if you can.

Comment: Aha—looks like Magento templates do something a little confusing. The template files are included *from inside a member function* of a class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239269/why-can-a-template-use-this-keyword-directly https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-this/ —basically, because the template files are included from within a method of Magento's block object, `$this` is available to them, and refers to the block object doing the including.

Comment: That's why I asked this question. They used in many places. But now I realized every $this have object .If we use get_class($this); function I always get some class. But The fact is I dont know how they using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to use $this in this way, you can create object of that class and then extend the methods which you would like to call. See below ...

```
class Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am an Animal!";
    }

    public function sayClassName() {
        $this->whichClass();
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am a Tiger!";
    }

    public function anotherClass() {
        echo "I am a another Tiger!";
    }

}

$tigerObj = new Tiger();

echo $tigerObj->anotherClass();
```

You will get result "I am a another Tiger!"

Answer (score 1):

$this is impossible to use outside class so you can make static method, and use like this Tiger::anotherClass. Link to [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.static.php)

```
class Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am an Animal!";
    }

    public function sayClassName() {
        $this->whichClass();
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am a Tiger!";
    }

    public static function anotherClass() {
        echo "I am a another Tiger!";
    }

}

$tigerObj = new Tiger();

//Tiger::whichClass();

Tiger::anotherClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

**NO you can't use $this outside the scope of a class**

example :

```
1    $this=new \DateTime();
2    echo $this->format('r');
```

generates the following error :

**`Fatal error:  Cannot re-assign $this on line 2`**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to use `$this` outside class with php 8.

Example: `class.php`

```php
<?php
class MyClass {
  private $say = '';
  public function say(string $text) {
    $this->say = $text;
  }

  public function hear() {
    require __DIR__ . '/test.php';
    echo $this->say;
  }
}
$MyClass = new MyClass();
$MyClass->hear();
?>
```

`test.php`

```php
<?php
$this->say('Using this Outside Class Is Possible');
?>
```